# Getting JSONException

Tags: android, json

I have a json object:

```
"images":{"1":{"imagename":"image1.gif","url":"image1url"},"2":{"imagename":"image2.gif","url":"image2url"},"3":{"imagename":"image3.gif","url":"image3url"}}
```

I want to fetch imagename and url from this. I enter into this images. I fetched the values 1,2,3 from images. But I am not able to fetch the json corresponding to this 1,2 and 3.

Its throwing exception stating: No value for 1
or No Value for 2
or No value for 3

What may be the reason for this cause? Please reply..

My present code is:

```
if(jsonObj.has("images")) {

    JSONArray imagesArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("images").names();
    JSONObject imageDetailsObject;

    for(int i = 0; i < imagesArray.length(); i++) {
       imageDetailsObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(imagesArray.get(i).toString());
       if(imageDetailsObject.has("imagename")) {
          //perform some actions
       }
       if(imageDetailsObject.has("url")) {
         //perform some actions
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked by giving:

```
if (jsonObj.has("images")) {

    JSONArray imagesArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("images").names();
    JSONObject imageDetailsObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesArray.length(); i++) {

        imageDetailsObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject(
                                        imagesArray.getString(i));
        if(imageDetailsObject.has("imagename")) {
            //perform some actions
        }
        if (imageDetailsObject.has("url")) {
            //perform some actions
        }
    }                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

```
imageDetailsObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject(imagesArray.get(i).toString());
```

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood your concept. It seems that you lost the jsonObj.getJSONObject("image"). So I edited my answer.